# rewrite keys of array by another array

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I want to rewrite array "foo"'s numeric keys with string keys. The relation is saved in another array "bar".

```
$foo = array(
 1 => 'foo',
 2 => 'bar',
 ...
);

$bar = array(
 1 => 'abc',
 2 => 'xyz',
 ...
);

$result = array(
 'abc' => 'foo',
 'xyz' => 'bar',
 ...
);
```

What is the fastest way to achieve this result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NullPointer's example will fail if the keys/values in both arrays ($foo and $bar) will be in different order. Consider this:

```
$foo = array(
    1 => 'foo',
    2 => 'bar',
);

$bar = array(
    2 => 'xyz',
    1 => 'abc',
);
```

If you run `array_combine($foo, $bar)` like before, the output will be

```
array(2) {
  ["foo"]=>
  string(3) "xyz"
  ["bar"]=>
  string(3) "abc"
}
```

This simple loop, however, should work:

```
$output = array();
foreach ($bar as $from => $to) {
    $output[$to] = $foo[$from];
}
```

Comment: Why not just `ksort` both arrays?  :P

Comment: Note that OP explicitly defined array indexes (`1 =>`), so I guess we can assume that it has already been taken care of, besides we can always *reindex* both arrays (e.g. `array_values`). `array_combine` seems to be short and simpler solution, at least for me.

Answer (score 7):

Use [`array_combine`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php) function:

```
$combined = array_combine($bar, $foo);
```

`print_r($combined);` gives

```
Array
(
    [abc] => foo
    [xyz] => bar
)
```